# Result not showing on clicking... What's the issue? can anybody help me?

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    async function redirect()
    {
       document.body.innerHTML = "";
       let n = await eel.generate_system_data()();
       var div = document.createElement("div")
       div.setAttribute("class","output");
       document.body.appendChild(div);

       var p = document.createElement("h1");
       var t = document.createTextNote("GENERATED RESULTS:");
       p.appendChild(t);
       div.appendChild(p);
       }
</script>
```

The Script is not showing any output? It's just blank... what's the error?

Comment: Are there supposed to be two function calls on this line let n = await eel.generate_system_data()();?

Comment: if this is all to it... it might be because its not being called? maybe you want to wrap it in a [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)